# Professional way to decline contract extension

Tags: job-offer, contract-extension

I’m on 6 month contract ending at the end of Oct. I’ve enjoyed my time there but for multiple reasons (distance, working hours and company culture etc.) I started looking for new roles.

I took 3 days off to interview at a new company and told boss I was very unwell. Upon returning to work, my boss said he’d been informed that I’m actively looking for jobs and that I should tell him now if I am leaving because he doesn’t want me working on new projects if I’m leaving. He also questioned why I would lie about being sick.

At this point I hadn’t been made an offer and didn’t think I was likely to. I didn’t want to shoot myself in the foot and cut all ties at my current role as he can react very nastily, so I told my boss I would like to stay.

Today I received the offer for the job I interviewed for and I intend on taking it. Now I feel guilty that I had the opportunity to tell my boss when asked, and I’m unsure the best way to approach the situation without looking like a complete liar.

I plan on telling him as soon as possible, any advice?

Comment: Have you been offered a contract extension with your current employer?

Comment: Yes. After weeks of saying ‘I need to prove myself’ in order for him to pay a lump sum in  recruitment fees, today he said he wants to offer a full time position.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere hard to tell tone in text, the full text above makes much more sense, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 8):

> and I’m unsure the best way to approach the situation without looking like a complete liar

It is too late for that since you already lied twice to your boss.  At this point all you can do is apologize for your dishonesty when you hand your boss your resignation.

In the future, if you are going to take time off for interviews and you have to give a reason, use something generic such as "I have an appointment".  Lying about being sick is never good as your boss/colleagues may care about your well-being and will be concerned for you.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the other answers would be more correct if you were a full time permanent employee,  but as you have a 6 month contract, your boss is not entitled to expect your loyalty, especially if they have not yet offered you an extension with 4 weeks left on your current contract.

You don't have any obligation to explain why you do not want to extend your contract.  If they offer you an extension simply refuse, politely.